# Remove hibernation from NTFS partiton

Tags: dual-boot, ntfs, hibernate

I have dual boot setup Windows 8 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have two NTFS partitions - C(system drive having windows 8) and D. I want to access D drive on Ubuntu and don't want to disable hibernation.

NOTE: I have created another NTFS partition from Ubuntu (E drive) and I can read/write it from Ubuntu even if windows hibernation is on. So why I can't D drive?

Is it possible? Can I remove hibernation from D drive? Or is there any other solution?

Thanks!

Comment: No Sir, I want to access **non system** but NTFS partition

Comment: That is the same isse; the partition it is about does not matter

Answer (score 0):

### Boot and reboot Windows

If you want to access to the Windows partition **temporarily**, you can boot and reboot Windows. At reboot it does not hibernate, and you should be able to make the computer boot into Ubuntu (instead of rebooting Windows). In this situation Windows should leave its file system such that Ubuntu can mount it.

**Warning:** It is safe read files, but it is risky to write files to the Windows system partition, which is usually C:

### Possible workaround with a USB drive

Maybe this workaround would work for you: If you have a USB drive (HDD, SSD, pendrive or memory card) with NTFS, I hope and think that Windows will flush its buffers at poweroff even when hibernating. Otherwise it would not be safe when moved to other computers with Windows, so I think Microsoft has made it work like this, but I have not tested it.

This means that a USB drive with NTFS should be available to mount in Ubuntu and safe to read and write after being used by Windows.

Comment: Thanks For reply. I am aware about mounting NTFS drive by turning hibernation off. However I can access new NTFS partition (E drive) but not existing, non system NTFS partition

Comment: I have read about a work-around, but never looked into the details and never used it. When I dual boot, I turn off hibernation and fast startup in Windows. And I use(d) a separate data partition with NTFS to store data files with access from both Ubuntu and Windows. (Now I seldom run Windows, so my data partition has a linux (ext) file system. - I will add another possible workaround in the answer.

Comment: Maybe the D: drive alias partition is a *dynamic partition*, while E: was created from Ubuntu so it is a normal partition. A dynamic partition has a proprietary format by Microsoft, and linux cannot manage such a partition.